# IIS request limit

Tags: asp.net, iis, request, limit

I created a website with asp.net and 
That website processes data in Database and writes to screen formatted XML ( not saved XML )

it's working well but when it gets consecutive 40-50 request, IIS don't response and is blocking.

I think IIS is able to get limited request for person, how can i change it?

Comment: I think you'll need to add more info...40-50 requests shouldn't be an issue for IIS. Its more likely elsewhere (e.g db connection leaks, timeouts/connection pool, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821268

You exhausted the thread pool usually.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a limit as per the application pool created on IIS.

If your website is taking a long request time. so it would help if you increased your

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your answer appears to be incomplete.