# Why do asynchronous client TCP operations appear to perform worse than synchronous TCP operations?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, async-await, tcpclient

I have written a high performance TCP server in C# using `SocketAsyncEventArgs`. I have been testing its performance with two very simple clients, each creating 2000 parallel continuous loops. One client makes use of asynchronous calls to `TcpClient`; the other makes use of synchronous calls.

**Asynchronous**

```
Parallel.For(0, numClients, parallelOptions, async i =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        var tcpClient = new TcpClient();

        try
        {
            await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(host, port);

            await tcpClient.GetStream().WriteAsync(message);

            var buffer = new byte[1024];
            await tcpClient.GetStream().ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1024);

            tcpClient.GetStream().Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}: {ex.Message}");
        }
        finally
        {
            tcpClient.Close();
            tcpClient.Dispose();
        }
    }
});
```

**Synchronous**

```
Parallel.For(0, numClients, parallelOptions, i =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        var tcpClient = new TcpClient();

        try
        {
            tcpClient.Connect(host, port);

            tcpClient.GetStream().Write(message);

            var buffer = new byte[1024];
            tcpClient.GetStream().Read(buffer, 0, 1024);

            tcpClient.GetStream().Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}: {ex.Message}");
        }
        finally
        {
            tcpClient.Close();
            tcpClient.Dispose();
        }
    }
});
```

The synchronous version iterates continuously without any errors.

The asynchronous version, however, results in many `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it` errors. My assumptions are that this client is flooding the TCP listen backlog queue, causing subsequent inbound connections to be rejected.

What's going on? How can I protect server throughput from clients that choose to connect asynchronously?

Comment: Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342006/iis-request-limit

Comment: If the call is to the same web service you can create one where you receive a list of the objects and then call it once. And other idea is to count an x amount of calls and the wait for them to complete and call again.

Comment: What are the values of: `numClients, parallelOptions`? All async calls are awaited so there shouldn't be an difference in actual simultaneous connections.

Comment: You should not be using an `async` delegate inside a `Parallel.For`, this results in an unawaitable `async void`. `Parallel.For` is primarily meant for CPU bound operations. For `async` IO bound use a `Select` or even just a `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

`Parallel.For` is designed to wait for completion of all tasks inside the loop. But in case of asynchronous calls the loop delegate completes immediately returning a promise for internal asynchronous call. However "nobody" outside does wait for this promise completion because `Parallel.For` isn't designed for that which leads to the situation when `Parallel.For` quickly fires the tasks which are able only to start very first asynchronous operation (which is `ConnectAsync`) and that in turns most likely leads to the SYN flooding. But there can be other side effects caused by the fact the asynchronous operations aren't awaited.